# how to use Zend_Soap_Client in windows server

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework, soap, zend-soap

I downloaded Zend framework, to my windows server...

now I tried to use it with this code:

```
// generate secret auth token
require_once 'Zend/Soap/Client.php';

$soapClient = new Zend_Soap_Client('http://TheSite.com/webservice.php?wsdl');
$response = 0;
$response = $soapClient->authorise('KEY');


if($response){//we are authorised
    echo $response;
}
```

and I get this weird fatal Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Sender] Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\inetpub\vhosts\gossipbingo.net\httpdocs\GossipApp\tests\vip-store\Zend\Soap\Client.php:995 
>   Stack trace: #0 D:\inetpub\vhosts\gossipbingo.net\httpdocs\GossipApp\tests\vip-store\Zend\Soap\Client.php(995): Zend_Soap_Client::_doRequest() #1 [internal function]: Zend_Soap_Client->_doRequest(Object(Zend_Soap_Client_Common), '_*doRequest('*_soapCall('authorise', Array, NULL, NULL, Array) #5 [internal f in D:\inetpub\vhosts\gossipbingo.net\httpdocs\GossipApp\tests\vip-store\Zend\Soap\Client.php on line 995

Answer (score 0):

try to open the web service url in the web browser. do you see a response?

if not, it means you have a wrong url for the web service or you're behind a firewall that blocks the request.

It doesn't seem to be a zend framework issue to me